# triggering python azure function getting secrets from key vault

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app, azure-sdk

I tried to run the python azure function triggered by the blob, which will get the Personal Access token saved in the key vault and run the DevOps pipeline. I tested the code locally and it works fine and when I include the code in the **init**.py file it is not triggering the pipeline. Even unable to debug the code as there is not much information provided.

Below is the code is written in the **init**.py file before deploying and i have provided the required libraries in the requirement.txt file

```
    import logging
    from azure.devops.connection import Connection
    from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
    import azure.functions as func

    from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
    from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

    credentials = ManagedIdentityCredential()

    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://myKeyvault.vault.azure.net", credential=credentials)
    Personal_Access_Token = secret_client.get_secret("devops-token")
    print(Personal_Access_Token.value)

    Organization_URL = 'https://dev.azure.com/org/'
    Project_Name = 'ProjectName'

    def create_pipeline_client():
        credentials = BasicAuthentication('',Personal_Access_Token.value)
        connection = Connection(base_url=Organization_URL,creds=credentials)
        pipeline_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_pipelines_client()
        return pipeline_client
        
    def build_pipeline(pipeline_id,run_params,pipeline_version=None):
        pipeline_client = create_pipeline_client()
        print("Running Pipeline with ID : "+ str(pipeline_id))
        try:
            pipeline_client.run_pipeline(run_parameters=run_params,project=Project_Name,pipeline_id=pipeline_id,pipeline_version=pipeline_version)
            print("Pipeline Run sucessfully activated")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Pipeline Failed with Exception : " + str(ex))


    def get_pipeline(pipeline_id,pipeline_version=None):
        pipeline_client = create_pipeline_client()
        pipeline = pipeline_client.get_pipeline(project=Project_Name,pipeline_id=pipeline_id,pipeline_version=pipeline_version)
        print(pipeline)
        
    def list_pipelines():
        pipeline_client = create_pipeline_client()
        pipeline_list = pipeline_client.list_pipelines(Project_Name)
        for item in pipeline_list:
            print(item)

    def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                     f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                     f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

        run_params = {'branch/tag':'master'}
        build_pipeline(1,run_params,None)
```

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

create system assigned/user assigned access object ID (SP) under identity in azure function.

Create Access policy with necessary access to the above SP in the key vault